# How to use sharedPrefrence putString?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I want to use sharedprefrence string form another activity but the value is not being passed it always passes the default value?
**Creation of variable toast Shows inp value but value is not being passed**

````
                name_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.name_next);
                sp= getSharedPreferences("name_pref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                name_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        inp = nameInput.getText().toString();
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor= sp.edit();
                        editor.putString(inp,nameInput);
                        editor.commit();
                        Toast.makeText(com.calmo.name.this,"welcome "+inp,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(name.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });```    
**Calling **
**The Value is always returned as error that is default**

```            SharedPreferences sp=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("name_pref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String name_in =sp.getString("inp","Error");
        name.setText(name_in);
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class AppSharedPreferences {
public static final String TAG = "AppSharedPreferences";
private static SharedPreferences sharedPref;

private String demo_string = "demo string's key"

public AppSharedPreferences() {

}

public static void init(Context context)
{
    if(sharedPref == null)
        sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
            context.getPackageName(), Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public static void setDemoString(String demoString) {
    Editor prefs = sharedPref.edit();
    prefs.putString(demo_string, demoString);
    prefs.apply();
}

public static String getDemoString() {
    return sharedPref.getString(demo_string, "");
}}
```

Put this wherever u want to use shared prefs:

```
AppSharedPreferences.init(this);
```

You can exchange `this` for `activity` or `context`, depending on where you use the code.

To set value in preference, use this code:

```
AppSharedPreferences.setDemoString("Some Text");
```

To get the value from preference:

```
String text = AppSharedPreferences.getDemoString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove
`inp = nameInput.getText().toString();`
under onclick
and change
`editor.putString(inp,nameInput);`
**to**
`editor.putString("inp",nameInput.getText().toString());`